# Plotting a robot's xy coordinates using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am very new to matplotlib and I am trying to learn on the job here.

I have the XY coordinates of a robot over a period of time and I want to plot these points to visualize the robot movement. My code below (this was possible by other stack overflow experts' generosity) provides a scatter plot of the coordinates. But, I really want just the last 30 entries. Each coordinate is from a frame of a video. The video is 30 frames per second. I want to plot the last second so that I can visualize the motion. each coordinate plotted should vanish after 1/30 of a second.

Say the coords list has 1800 points, representing 60 seconds of data. I want to plot from the beginning of the list, one point per 1/30 of second and when the number of points on the plot reach 30, before 31st index is plotted, the 0th index point is removed from the plot and so one for every successive point from the coords list, till the end. This I think will simulate as if the robot is moving leaving behind a trail of its points for the last 1 second.

I have no idea how to plot a point and let that vanish from the frame after a period of time while new point is plotted. This will simulate a motion.

```
# read_data() returns a list of tuples of xy coordinates
coords = read_data()

x_list = [int(pt[0]) for pt in coords]
y_list = [int(pt[1]) for pt in coords]
x_min, x_max = min(x_list), max(x_list)
y_min, y_max = min(y_list), max(y_list)

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.add_patch(  # draw the bounday of the robot movements based on the min and max of coordinates
    patches.Rectangle(
        (x_min, y_min),  # (x,y)
        x_max - x_min,  # width
        y_max - y_min,  # height
        linewidth=0.1,
        fill=False
    )
)
ax1.plot(x_list, y_list, 'or', linewidth=0, markersize=0.2)  # plot the whole set

#  what I really need is just the last 30 entries; each entry comes in 1/30th of a second in actual env
```

Comment: Not quite. Say the coords list has 1800 points, representing 60 seconds of data. I want to plot from the beginning of the list, one point per 1/30 of second and when the number of points on the plot reach 30, before 31st index is plotted, the 0th index point is removed from the plot and so one for every successive point from the coords list, till the end. This I think will simulate as if the robot is moving leaving behind a trail of its points for the last 1 second.

Comment: Animations can be done using e.g. the `FuncAnimation` class. You will find hundreds of examples online. If you have problems with the implementation, provide a  [mcve] of the issue, such that people would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue recently, as I was in need of illustrating some motion-tracking data. I assume you solved this in another way (congrats!), but leaving this here for posterity's sake, regardless.

I ended up making it work with Dash (https://plotly.com/dash/).

If you replace the values in the dataframe "df" with your x's and y's, you should have something that does what (I think) you requested. If you replaced the contents of list x and list y with your data, you should be able to get something like what you request.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# defining the number of steps
n = 3000

#creating two arrays for containing x and y coordinate -- these are the lists you need to change
#of size equals to the number of size and filled up with 0's
x = 100 + np.zeros(n)
y = 100 + np.zeros(n)

# filling the coordinates with random variables
for i in range(1, n):
    val = random.randint(1, 4)
    if val == 1:
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1
        y[i] = y[i - 1]
    elif val == 2:
        x[i] = x[i - 1] - 1
        y[i] = y[i - 1]
    elif val == 3:
        x[i] = x[i - 1]
        y[i] = y[i - 1] + 1
    else:
        x[i] = x[i - 1]
        y[i] = y[i - 1] - 1

df = {'X': x, 'Y': y, 'Sample no.': [ind+1 for ind, x in enumerate(x)]}

indx=[ind for ind, x in enumerate(df['Y'])]

time_df = pd.DataFrame({"time": [0], "df_len": [len(df['X'])]})

def df_cond(series, last_n, tail):
    if last_n < tail:
        s = series[0: last_n]
    else:
        s = series[(last_n-tail): last_n]

    return s

def change(dataframe, size):

    try:
        dataframe['time'][0] = dataframe['time'][0] + int(size)
        return dataframe['time'][0]

    except:
        return dataframe['time'][0]

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='auto_speed', value=1, type='number'),
            ], className="two columns"),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='trail', value=100, type='number'),
            ], className="two columns"),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='man_start', value=0, type='number'),
            ], className="two columns"),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='man_end', value=0, type='number'),
            ], className="two columns"),
        ], className="row"),


    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Div(id='auto_description'),
            ], className="six columns"),

        html.Div([
            html.Div(id='man_description')
            ], className="six columns"),
        ], className="row"),

    dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        ),

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='behaviour', style={'width': 950, 'height': 950}, ),
            ], className="six columns"),

        html.Div([

            dcc.Graph(
                id='behaviour_full',
                style={'width': 950, 'height': 950},
                figure={
                    'data': [
                        dict(

                            x=df['X'],
                            y=df['Y'],

                            hovertext="xs and ys",
                            hoverinfo="text",
                            showlegend = True,
                            name = "Sample nr: {} - {} of {}".format(0, len(df['X']), len(df['X'])),
                            mode='markers',
                            opacity=0.7,
                            marker={
                                'size': 5,
                                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
                            }

                        )
                    ],

                    'layout': dict(
                        xaxis={'type': 'linear', 'title': 'x-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                        yaxis={'type': 'linear','title': 'y-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                        hovermode='closest',
                        transition = {'duration': 1}
                    )

                })

                ], className="six columns"),

        ], className="row"),

    # Hidden div inside the app that stores the intermediate value
    html.Div(id='intermediate-value', style={'display': 'none'})
])

#callbacks are activated, when they receive input -- so a callback including an interval-component, will update at the interval-component update-rate
@app.callback(
    Output('intermediate-value', 'children'),

    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
    Input('auto_speed', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_start', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_end', component_property='value')]
)
def clean_data(value, size, man_start, man_end):
    if man_start == -1:
        time_df['time'][0] = man_end
        print("zeroed")
        return time_df['time'][0]

    elif type(man_start) is int and type(man_end) is int and (man_end - man_start) > 0:
        return change(time_df, 0)

    else:
        return change(time_df, size)

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='behaviour', component_property='figure'),

    [Input(component_id='auto_speed', component_property='value'),
    Input('intermediate-value', 'children'),
    Input(component_id='trail', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_start', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_end', component_property='value'),]
)
def update_figure(interval, last_n, tail, man_start, man_end):

    if type(man_start) is int and type(man_end) is int and (man_end - man_start) > 0:
        return {
            'data': [
                dict(

                    x=df['X'][man_start: man_end],
                    y=df['Y'][man_start: man_end],

                    hovertext=["X: {}<br>Y: {}<br>Sample: {}".format(df['X'][man_start: man_end][i], df['Y'][man_start: man_end][i], indx[i]+1) for i in indx[man_start: man_end]],
                    hoverinfo="text",
                    showlegend = True,
                    name = "Sample nr: {} - {} of {} <br>{}".format(man_start, man_end, len(df['X']), interval),
                    mode='markers',
                    opacity=0.7,
                    marker={
                        'size': 5,
                        'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
                    }

                )
            ],

            'layout': dict(
                xaxis={'type': 'linear', 'title': 'x-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                yaxis={'type': 'linear','title': 'y-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                hovermode='closest',
                uirevision= 'dataset',
                transition = {'duration': 1}
            )

        }

    else:

        if last_n is None:
            last_n = 0

        return {
            'data': [
                dict(
                    x=df_cond(df['X'], last_n, tail),
                    y=df_cond(df['Y'], last_n, tail),

                    hovertext=["X: {}<br>Y: {}<br>Sample: {}".format(df['X'][i-1], df['Y'][i-1], df['Sample no.'][i-1]) for i in df_cond(df['Sample no.'], last_n, tail)],
                    hoverinfo="text",
                    showlegend = True,
                    name = "Sample nr: {} - {} of {} <br>{}".format(last_n - len(df_cond(df['X'], last_n, tail))+1, last_n, len(df['X']), interval),
                    mode='markers',
                    opacity=0.7,
                    marker={
                        'size': 5,
                        'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
                    }

                )
            ],

            'layout': dict(
                xaxis={'type': 'linear', 'title': 'x-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                yaxis={'type': 'linear','title': 'y-positions', 'range': [0,200]},
                hovermode='closest',
                uirevision= 'dataset',
                transition = {'duration': 1}
            )

        }



@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='auto_description', component_property='children'),

    [Input(component_id='auto_speed', component_property='value'),
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
    Input(component_id='man_start', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_end', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='trail', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value, n_intervals, man_start, man_end, tail):

    if man_start == -1:
        return ' Auto sample index set to: {}'.format(man_end)

    elif type(man_start) is int and type(man_end) is int and (man_end - man_start) > 0:
        return ' Manual values being used.'

    else:
        if tail > time_df['time'][0]:
            return ' Automatic slice: {} - {}'.format(0, time_df['time'][0])

        else:
            return ' Automatic slice: {} - {}'.format(time_df['time'][0]-tail, int(time_df['time'][0]))

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='man_description', component_property='children'),

    [Input(component_id='man_start', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='man_end', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(start_val, end_val):
    if start_val is None:
        return ' Using auto slice'

    elif start_val == -1:
        return ' Setting auto sample index to: {}'.format(end_val)

    elif end_val - start_val  > 0:
        return ' Manual slice: {} - {}'.format(start_val, end_val)

    else:
        return ' Using auto slice'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You can see the illustration by entering the address from the line that says "Running on http://(...)" line in your terminal.

Apropos letting points vanish from the frame -- what is done in this script is basically just a redrawing of a new part of the sample data. I am fairly sure my solution is woefully inefficient. But it does what I need it to do.